# Design path overlapping issue with blending modes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, blend-modes

Hey I'm very new to illustrator. I've made a design with the pen tool (path), it has a few overlapping shapes and looked ok. But once I started playing around with blending modes the edges/overlapping bits of the stroke stand out and I can't figure out how to combine the shape somehow to avoid this?

I circled the problem areas here in the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand strokes and merge the shapes ...

... or ...

... group all the strokes and apply any blending mode to the entire *group* via the Appearance Panel, rather than applying it to the individual paths ...

... or ...

... place all the strokes on a single, independent, Layer and apply any blending mode to the *layer* via the Appearance Panel ...

... or ...

... don't use blending modes. Often one can change the color of an object rather than relying on blending modes to change colors for you. After all, blending modes merely change colors, nothing more.

[image]